# Scope inheritance with nested states inside of Angular 1's Components

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-components

I'm having difficult getting the controller to link up to nested states within Angular components.

For example, I have the following parent component:

```
export default {
  restrict: 'E',
  bindings: {},
  template,
  controller
};
```

The code above defines the controller and templates for an Angular component. This gets defined as a module and as a component that the app consumes:

```
export default angular
  .module('parentComponent', [uiRouter, goalServices])
  .config(parentComponentConfig)
  .component('parentComponent', parentComponentComponent)
  .name;
```

Inside of the config file above, I'm setting the states that route the states to their URL and templates:

```
export default ($stateProvider) => {
  'ngInject';

   $stateProvider
     .state('create-goal', {
       url: '/create-goal',
       abstract: true
     })
    .state('create-goal.step1', {
       url: '/step1',
       template: template1
    });
 };
```

How would I be able to get access to the parent controller within the substate of `create-goal.step1`? In the other component's that I have in our app, since the module is defined with the controller, the templates are linked up, however, the only way I could get this to work was the following changes:

```
export default ($stateProvider) => {
  'ngInject';

   $stateProvider
     .state('create-goal', {
       url: '/create-goal',
       controller,
       controllerAs: 'vm',
       abstract: true
     })
    .state('create-goal.step1', {
       url: '/step1',
       template: template1
    });
 };
```

As you can see above, I had to define the controller within the state, unlike before where I defined it within the module definition file. I also need to add the `controllerAs`, because in these views, the `$ctrl` syntax doesn't work in the child components.

Any ideas? Am I missing something here or for nested components, the controllers get defined within the the `$stateProviders` rather than the component definitions?

Comment: as far as I understand, you have to define (or pass a reference) to the component or child component when defining a state, have you checked the [docs](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component#update-the-state-definition) for ui-router with components?

Comment: Component scope is bound to parent scope with the `bindings` property. For more information,  see [AngularJS Guide - Component-based application architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture)